# Generating very large PDF file

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, pdf, stream, streaming

I'm trying to generate a large PDF file with the following setup:

1. I have a input stream of data I need to write. This data takes the form of a table row.
2. I have an output stream to a file.

Given a very, very long stream of input data, I need to generate a PDF file that shows this data.

For example the data could be something like:

```
Fred Jones, Checking Account, 104543, Withdrawal, $140
Charlie Smith, Checking Account, 104543, Deposit, $151
Judie Allen, Savings Account, 104543, Withdrawal, $158
Ali Wahim, Checking Account, 104543, Deposit, $10
```

Exporting this data as CSV is quite simple. All you have to do is write to the output stream with comma separation.

I am having trouble doing a similar process with a PDF...

It seems that from the Golang PDF libraries I can see, I can only generate a PDF given some data stored in memory or combine a PDF (by loading the two PDFs I'm combining in memory). It does not look like there is any way to generate a PDF by **streaming** data to output.

Has anyone done this before? Maybe even outside of the Golang environment?

Comment: What do you mean by streaming data to output? Write to an io.Writer?

Comment: @topskip yes stream to an io.Writer

Comment: So you just want to stream text and newlines and this gets converted to a PDF broken into pages?

Comment: @topskip I want to format the text in a row and stream that into a PDF made up of pages. For now, just streaming words to a pdf is enough if I can do that.

Comment: @KJ This will require having the pdf in memory, and it will be extremely big so it is  not be possible to store in memory.